# does google maps v3 reverse geocoding has usage limit

Tags: google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I don't know where to ask so I hope this is the place

I want to ask if google maps v3 reverse geocode  has a limit! I ask because Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day.

```
function codeLatLng(newPosition) {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(newPosition.lat(), newPosition.lng());
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
  {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
    {
      if (results[1]) 
      {

        formattedaddress = results[0].formatted_address;
        alert (formattedaddress);

      } 
      else 
      {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Both the geocoder and reverse geocoder are subject to a rate limit and a quota.

If exceeded you will get a status of [google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes)